# changing default root directory of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Can anybody tell me that where in configuration files it is defined that by default on running

http:/localhost:8080/

it will open index.html of the ROOT application(in webapp)?

Answer (score 2):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

> If the context path is the empty string them the base name will be
>   ROOT (always in upper case) otherwise the base name will be the
>   context path with the leading '/' removed and any remaining '/'
>   characters replaced with '#'.